# Slice a video with ffmpeg based on frame position

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'd like to extract a slice of video from a video. Unfortunately, I do not have the start time position and duration to run ffmpeg like so:

```
ffmpeg -sameq -ss [start_seconds] -t [duration_seconds] -i [input_file] [outputfile]
```

Instead, I have the first and the last frame number. So... is it possible to slice a mp4 video with ffmpeg based on frame position?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the file has audio, which also needs to be correspondingly sliced, then you will need to know the start time and duration. Unless the video is variable frame rate, start frame index `I` is at time `I/FPS` and end frame `O` is at time `O/FPS` where FPS is the frame rate of the video. Running `ffprobe [input_file]` will give you the frame rate reading.

Else use,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf trim=start_frame=I:end_frame=O+1 -an output.mp4
```

`-sameq` is deprecated and does *not* mean same quality. This command will skip the audio as it can't be cut with reference to video frame indices.

Comment: The stated command doesn't shift the timestamps, you end up with a video that starts with timestamps like `2:07`, even if the cutout is only a few seconds long. Fix this with `-vf "trim=start_frame=I:end_frame=O+1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS"`. I also had to use `O+2` to get the expected frame count in the resulting video, not sure why.